# Задний фон подбивался под размеры

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Всем доброго времени суток.
На сайте есть "шапка",фон белый.Я задал её высоту 110px.Ничего не выступает за рамки.Но если в магазине применить фильтр,то в этой "шапке" появятся список примененных критериев,тем самым увеличится высота текста в "шапке",а сам бг останется 110px.Каким способом можно решить эту проблемы?
Заранее благодарю за ответы.
Сам сайт http://tiarsekj.bget.ru/shop/

Шапка в спокойном состоянии
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Шапка с фильтрами
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у элементов "page-title" и "woof_products_top_panel" нужно убирать margin-bottom после добавления элемента.

Comment: Да,вы помогли,благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здравствуйте, у вас при применении фильтра появляется элемент .woof_products_top_panel который своей высотой и margin выталкивает панель с фильтром. Попробуйте убрать у этого элемента margin и line-height.

Comment: Да,все правильно,благодарю.